# linear algebra (partial) solving in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a dictionary with a tuple as key and a result as value.
I'm looking for a way to "solve" as many keys as possible, even if it's not possible to "solve" all of then.

```
input : {(A, C):1,(A, B, C): 1}
output : {(A, C):1, (A, B, C): 1, B:0}
```

in other word :

```
modified input : 
    1*A + 0*B + 1*C = 1
    1*A + 1*B + 1*C = 1
output :
A = ?
B = 0
C = ?
```

I can only use numpy and scipy.

I tried this, but it must be square matrix :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([1, 1])
from scipy import linalg
x = linalg.solve(a, b)
print(x)
```

Do you have ideas where I should look at ?

this code does the trick, but it's not very 'clean'

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
B=np.array([1,1])
s = solutionNonSquare = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
for i,val in enumerate(s):
    if val < 0.0001:
        print('x[',i,'] = 0')
    else:
        print('x[',i,'] = ?')

print(s)
```

Thanks a lot for your smartness

Comment: This is an underdetermined system... what exactly are you looking for here? A symbolic answer?

Comment: yes, exactly, this is an underdetermined system. But, my system can be simplified, because some values = 0 . I want to find them. I've just edited a little bit my question

Answer (score 0):

Matrix `a` is Non square Matrix, so it does not have full Rank. However, we can compute pseudo inverse, using `np.linalg.pinv` and then we can compute `x = np.matmul(a_psudo_inv, b)`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([1, 1])
from numpy import linalg


a_psudo_inv = np.linalg.pinv(a)
print(a_psudo_inv)

print(a_psudo_inv.shape)
x = np.matmul(a_psudo_inv, b)
print(x)
```

Solution `>> [5.00000000e-01 5.55111512e-16 5.00000000e-01]`